# Why same Regular expression have diff behavior

Tags: perl

i need to capture sub-string from a string. For that i am using one Regx but that is not working as expected in my code.

The strange thing is that same regx is working fine if i am not taking input from user :

Here is my code :

**Case one : Working Fine**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path = "\\\\xyz\\abc\\def\\Logs\\LA.1.0\\04.04.04.128.281\\September-10---15.28.5\\wxzLogs\\PostBootLogs\\Complete_Logs_2014091016000\\ANR\\traces.txt_20140910204706";
my ($captured) = $path =~ /(.+?) \\PostBootLogs/x;
print "$captured\n";
```

**Cas-2 Not Working :**

```
my $path = $ARGV[0];
copylog($path);

sub copylog {
    print "Before_path -> $path\n";
    my ($captured) = $path =~ /(.+?) \\PostBootLogs/x;
    print "After_path -> $path\n";
}
```

In both the case i am using same string . i need to use the regx in second case so can any body tell me what is wrong with second case.

Comment: How do you invoke the script? Show the full command line, please.

Comment: You're printing out `$path`, not `$captured` in the second script. `$path` has the original data in it, `$captured` has the matched portion.

Comment: Sorry guys for asking such silly question .. that was my mistake . I did not noticed that i am not printing proper veriable.

Comment: Please write standard English, including capitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are print the wrong variable , because In first case you had print `$captured` variable 
But in next case you had print `$path`,So you can print `$captured` ,you get the exact result.

```
print "After_path -> $captured\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash you don't need to quote backslashes inside single quotes. That is you are to type
'\xyz\abc\def\Logs\LA.1.0...'. Hope that will help.